# How to change the time period that pandas resample evaluates?

Tags: python, pandas, series

Based on the example from https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html, I try to aggregate my time data on three minute intervals using pandas `resample`

```
index = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=9, freq='T')
series = pd.Series(range(9), index=index)
series.resample('3T').sum()

#Output:
#2000-01-01 00:00:00     3
#2000-01-01 00:03:00    12
#2000-01-01 00:06:00    21
```

The resample function only runs on the time period of `index` (here from `00:00:00` to `00:08:00`). How can I change the time period `resamples` evaluates (eg `from = '1999-12-31 23:54:00', to = '2000-01-01 00:15:00')`?

So, the desired output would be:

```
#1999-12-31 23:54:00   NaN 
#1999-12-31 23:57:00   NaN   
#2000-01-01 00:00:00     3
#2000-01-01 00:03:00    12
#2000-01-01 00:06:00    21
#2000-01-01 00:09:00   NaN
#2000-01-01 00:12:00   NaN
#2000-01-01 00:15:00   NaN
```

Comment: @yatu Thanks for the reminder. I wait until I fully understood the answer and have no further need for clarification. Currently I'm lacking understanding of the index in pandas...